# Where can I find financial data for the first world war?

Tags: war, economy, world-war-one

I want to analyse the first world war on the financial aspect. Here are some of my questions.

- Which countries borrowed money to win the war?
- Where were weapons manufactured?

Where can I get information about these topics?

Google at least just shows me current bank problems with these keywords.

Comment: In its current form, this question is not a good fit for this site. Any question that solicits the creation of a list of source is unacceptable. The individual questions you gave as examples, on the other hand, would be a perfect fit. I have to close this question, but I would strongly suggest you ask the other questions separately.

Answer (score 2):

Palmer's history of the modern world (10th edition) recommonds the following two books which should include information on the various economic aspects of WWI:

- G. Hardach: *The First World War* (1977)
- D. Stevenson: *The First World War and International Politics* (1988)

Comment: Hi, I will take a look at them and give feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a copy of *First World War Atlas* by **Martin Gilbert** (SBN 297 17847 4).

There are a couple of fascinating maps near the end.

**European Debts to Britain**

- Russia - £757 million
- France - £626 million
- Italy - £590 million
- Yugoslavia - £30 million
- Rumania (sic) - £26 million
- Portugal - £23 million
- Greece - £21 million
- Austria* - £11 million
- Belgium* - £9 million - a note reminds us that an additional £110 million of Belgium's debt was to be paid by Germany
- Poland* - £5 million

* - 1919 - 25 - British loans for reconstruction

**European Debts to the United States**

- Britain - $4,277 million
- France - $2,997 million
- Italy - $1,640 million
- Belgium - $349 million
- Russia - $187 million
- Poland* - $160 million
- Czechoslovakia - $62 million
- Rumania (sic) - $25 million
- Yugoslavia* - $25 million
- Austria* - $24 million
- Greece - $15 million
- Estonia* - $14 million
- Armenia* - $12 million
- Finland* - $8 million
- Latvia* - $5 million
- Lithuania* - $5 million
- Hungary* - $1 million

* - 1919 - 25 - US loans for reconstruction

Footnote:

> War debts were payable to the U.S. over 62 years at an interest rate of just over 2%. Armenia never came into existence as an independent state, and thus none of its debt was paid. Finland alone of 19 nations had paid her debt in full by 1969. In 1925 the United States cancelled 80% of the Italian debt. In 1926 60% of the French debt was cancelled. The Bolshevik Government of Russia rejected the demand that it honour Tsarist debt.